# How to change calendar permissions for all members of a group?

Tags: powershell, permissions, calendar

I'm currently trying to use powershell to change Outlook calendar permissions for a subset of users, so that they can all view calendar details of one another.

So far, I have been able to find the commands to change permissions for a single user, and for all users in the org - but have not yet established how to apply these changes to just a group.

Here is the script I found to modify permissions for all users:

```
foreach($user in Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox) {

$cal = $user.alias+”:\Calendar”

Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $cal -User Default -AccessRights LimitedDetails

}
```

In order to apply this to just a group of users, would my modifications below be correct?

```
foreach($user in Get-MsolGroupMember -Identity "Name of Group") {

$cal = $user.alias+”:\Calendar”

Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $cal -User Default -AccessRights LimitedDetails

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first find the group as object, because `Get-MsolGroupMember` doesn't have a `-Identity` parameter.
Then use that to get info of its users:

```
$groupToFind = 'DisplayName of Group'
$permissions = 'LimitedDetails'
$group = Get-MsolGroup | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $groupToFind }
if ($group) {
    # get the group members (users only) and run through
    Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $group.ObjectId -MemberObjectTypes User -All | ForEach-Object {
        $cal   = '{0}:\Calendar' -f $_.Alias
        $perms = Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $cal -User Default
        if ($perms.AccessRights -contains $permissions) {
                Write-Host "User $($_.Alias) already has the '$permissions' permission"
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Setting permissions on $cal"
            # for safety, first run with the -WhatIf switch. If you are satisfied with what
            # is output on screen, remove or comment out that switch and run again
            Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $cal -User Default -AccessRights $permissions -WhatIf
        }
    }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find group '$groupToFind'..."
}
```

<sup>Instead of using the Where-Object clause on `Get-MsolGroup`, you could also do `Get-MsolGroup -SearchString $groupToFind`, but beware that using `-SearchString` will return groups that have a display name that START with this string.</sup>

---

If you receive *"The command completed successfully, no permissions were changed"*, this could mean the user first needs to get permissions on the so-called top of the information store (i.e. the mailbox folder itself):

```
Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $group.ObjectId -MemberObjectTypes User -All | ForEach-Object {
    $top = '{0}:\' -f $_.Alias            # Top of Information Store
    $cal = '{0}:\Calendar' -f $_.Alias

    Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $top -User Default -AccessRights FolderVisible -Confirm:$false
    Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $cal -User Default -AccessRights LimitedDetails -Confirm:$false
}
```

P.S. Because Outlook runs in  cache, it takes time to reflect the changes there.

Comment: Thanks for your help Theo.

Apologies, I don't know where in that script would I add a -WhatIf switch and how would that change how it runs?

Comment: @CivicTeam It's already in the code as last parameter of the `Set-MailboxFolderPermission` line. In the comments above it I tried to explain. **With** `-WhatIf`, the command is not carried out, only what _would_ happen is displayed. **Without** the command is executed.

Comment: thanks for your help with the script and the platform - the script appears to complete correctly with the -WhatIf switch, but upon doing Get-Mailboxfolderpermission on one of the users in the group, the permissions are still not applied. Should I create a different type of group such as a distribution list? It's currently a Microsoft365 group.

Comment: @CivicTeam No, the command to apply changes is `Set-MailboxFolderPermission`, not `Get-MailboxFolderPermission`.. If you remove `-WhatIf` in my code, the setting should be performed. If there is one user that causes problems, see what the error message is. Did that user ever log in?

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear, I allowed the script to complete on the target group, and removing the `-WhatIf` so that it would actually apply. I was met with a "The command completed successfully, no permissions were changed" type information alert. Afterwards, I did a `Get-MailboxFolderPermission` to check that it had applied, and there were no changes on the user's (in the group) calendar.

Comment: @CivicTeam Please see my edit. I think that has to do with the top-level not being accessible for the user, so no permission change is possible. I have also added `-Confirm:$false`, but if you want confirmation, you can always remove that or set it to `-Confirm:$true`

Comment: Still no joy unfortunately, still getting the `WARNING: The command completed successfully but no permissions of Identity:'admin:\Calendar' have been modified.`

Interestingly, the error mentions the permissions of the account which is being used to connect to MsOnline, rather than the group members that are being called?

Comment: @CivicTeam Weird... Try with a different user and perhaps even (although that should not be necessary) use [Remove-MailboxFolderPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/remove-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps) first, then add the new permission.

Comment: Could it be simpler for a script to change default calendar sharing permissions for users of a group, as opposed to explicitly for each the group members?

Comment: @CivicTeam That I don't know. Perhaps via Group Policy? BTW, I have added a test in my first code so now it tests whether that permission is already granted or not first